Pauli displacements of a GKP lattice state
In this review of GKP codes, in Section IV B, they discuss GKP codes from a lattice perspective. For a GKP lattice state $\mathcal{L}$, they say that the Pauli displacement vectors $\mathbf{p} \in \{\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{z}\}$, i.e., the displacement vectors that implement the logical Pauli operators (e.g., $X_L = D_{\mathbf{x}}$), are the smallest vectors of the dual lattice $\mathcal{L}^*$. The norms $\|\mathbf{x}\|$, $\|\mathbf{y}\|$, and $\|\mathbf{z}\|$ represent the Pauli distances of the GKP code. The generator of the dual lattice is $M^* = M A^{-T}$, where $A$ is the Gram matrix $A = M^T \Omega M$, $M$ is the generator of the GKP lattice state $\mathcal{L}$, and $\Omega$ is a $2N \times 2N$ matrix representing the $N$-mode symplectic form:
$$
\Omega = \bigoplus_{i=1}^N \Omega_1, \quad \Omega_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
They state:

The Pauli displacements can, more or less, be associated with the columns (or rows) of $M^*$.

For example, for a two-mode ($N=2$) Tesseract qubit (Example IV.7 in the paper), the generator of the dual lattice is:
$$
M(\square^2)^* = \frac{\Omega \tilde{O}}{ \sqrt[4]{2}},
$$
where $\tilde{O}$ is a $4\times4$ non-symplectic orthogonal transformation (see Eq. 75 in the paper). For which they say:

$M(\square^2)^*$ is enough to show that $\|\mathbf{x}_{\square^2}\| = \|\mathbf{z}_{\square^2}\| = \frac{1}{ \sqrt[4]{2}}$ and $\|\mathbf{y}_{\square^2}\| =  \sqrt[4]{2}$.

From this, it's unclear to me which columns of the $4\times4$ matrix $M(\square^2)^*$ correspond to which Pauli displacements.
Question: How are the Pauli displacements determined from the dual lattice generator matrix
$M^*$, for the Tesseract qubit example, and in general?

The general version of your question is answered in Section IV of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2410.07332 and I'll summarise the main points below.
Given a (symplectically integral) lattice $\mathcal{L}$ there always exists a generator matrix $M = (\xi_1, \dots, \xi_{2n})^{T}$ such that the Gram matrix $A = M J M^T$ assumes a unique standard form $A = J_2 \otimes D$. Here I used $J$ for the symplectic form, but $\Omega$ works the same. In the standard form $D = \text{diag}(d_1, \dots, d_n)$ with $d_i$ positive integers which is enough for our case. The standard form becomes unique for any given lattice $\mathcal{L}$ if one adds the requirement $d_n |d_{n-1} | \dots |d_1$ (read $d_{n}$ divides $d_{n-1}$ etc.).
Now the Gram matrix $A^\perp$ of the dual lattice $\mathcal{L}^\perp$ is of the form $A^\perp = J_2 \otimes D^{-1}$. This Gram matrix is generated from the generator matrix $M^\perp$ satisfying $M^\perp J M^T = I$. This means the rows $\xi_i^\perp$ of $M^\perp$ have pairwise vanishing symplectic product except for $\xi_i^{\perp, T} J \xi_{i+n}^{\perp} = 1/d_{i}$ (or in the $\Omega$ convention $\xi_i^{\perp, T} J \xi_{i+1}^{\perp} = 1/d_{i}$ for odd $i$).
The displacement operators associated to these dual lattice generators then satisfy the commutation relationships of multiple qudit Pauli groups, i.e. for $\bar{X}_i = D(\xi_i^{\perp})$ and $\bar{Z}_i = D(\xi_{i+n}^{\perp})$ one has that
$$\bar{X}_i \bar{Z}_i  = \text{exp} (-2 \pi i /d_i)\bar{Z}_i \bar{X}_i$$
and all other pairs $\bar{X}_i, \bar{Z}_j \, i \neq j$ commute. Because these operators commute with all GKP stabilizers and fulfill the correct commutation relations they are the logical Pauli operators you are looking for.
Now we said above that the matrix $D$ is not unique without the extra requirement that $d_n |d_{n-1} | \dots |d_1$. This means that each $D$ gives a different decomposition of your logical code space into a tensor product of qudits, with the unique standard form fixing a particular one.
